# How to get around iOS 7 UI notification symbol not found when running on iOS 6 device?

Tags: ios

I'm stumped.  I've read (and tried) about 30 answers here and elsewhere about checking system version numbers, features and selectors.  But this isn't a selector that's not available in previous OS versions, it's a UI notification.

The code in question is basic:

```
        [nc addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(screenShotTaken:)
                   name:UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification
                 object:nil];
```

It compiles fine.  Runs fine on iOS 7 devices.  On iOS 6.1 devices the app dies on launch:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification
```

As long as that code is present the runtime wants to find that symbol.  I can get it dead-stripped out by wrapping it:

```
if (1 == 2) {
    [nc addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(screenShotTaken:)
               name:UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification
             object:nil];
}
```

But then it won't run on iOS 7 devices.

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: It is just a call to my analytics manager recording the fact that the user had taken a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to set the deployment target back from iOS 7 to iOS 6.  Then the runtime test can avoid the registration for an iOS 7-only notification correctly:

```
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    [nc addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(screenShotTaken:)
               name:UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification
             object:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, iDev, for your suggestions.  But they didn't address my issue.  My app is not concerned with changes to the status bar orientation.  It is interested in knowing when the user has taken a screen shot.  But the core issue was that with iOS 7 as the deployment target that iOS 7-only symbol was expected to be present even on iOS 6.

Answer (score -1):

iOS 6 and lower you can use

```
UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
```

**UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification**

Posted when the user presses the Home and Lock buttons to take a screenshot.
This notification does not contain a userInfo dictionary. This notification is posted after the screenshot is taken.

Availability
**Available in iOS 7.0 and later.**

**Note:** UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification is posted after the screenshot is taken. Currently there is no way to be notified before a screenshot is taken, which could be useful for hiding an embarrassing photo. Hopefully Apple adds an `UIApplicationUserWillTakeScreenshotNotification in iOS 8! :]`

referenced by 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/48001/easily-overlooked-new-features-ios-7#screenshot

Comment: Yeah, but that's not what I'm asking about.  The symbol doesn't exist in iOS 6 so the app crashes.  I'm currently mulling over creating a symbol when running under iOS 6 so the runtime has something to appease it, and using a test to ensure I don't register for the iOS 7-only notification when running under iOS 6.

Comment: you should check os version of notification method

Comment: ios 6 and lower you can use UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification